# changing default coding in TeX

Tags: winedt

Just installed WinEdt cannot SAVE Russian characters. It warns:
``Some characters were lost while converting from UNICODE to CP 0. Save anyway?''
Probably, TeX converts all files to Unicode, but my old files are in 1251, and it cannot work with them. How to change the default coding to 1251?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! If you know the old encoding, you'd better use the dedicated tool `Convert to UTF8` in the `File` menu.